# If $3 \sin \theta + 4 \cos \theta = 5$, find the value of $\sin \theta$.

Tags: trigonometry

What would be the answer for the following question?

> If $3 \sin \theta + 4 \cos \theta = 5$, find the value of $\sin \theta$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Divide by 5, and use the addition formula.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903629/how-would-we-solve-this-trigonometric-equation-using-vectors and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397670/finding-trignometric-equation and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866493/solve-3-sin-theta4-cos-theta-0 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362377/connection-between-the-expression-4-sin-x-3-cos-x-and-the-equation-cos-3 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293546/write-5-sin-theta-12-cos-theta-as-a-single-cosine

Comment: There's a decent chance that the approach in that question isn't going to help the OP, although it's hard to tell what level they may be at.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) Such information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve your understanding, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3463466/edit) to add details.

Comment: Also, since they need to find $\sin\theta$ and not $\theta$ itself, it's likely they're meant to just apply some trig identities.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750752/when-combining-wave-functions-what-do-the-different-forms-signify and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292541/trigonometry-express-4-cos-x3-sin-x-in-the-form-r-cos-xa and probably 80 or 90 others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you can use, that keeps things relatively simple, is to do this:

First, rearrange the equation to $4 \cos \theta = 5 - 3 \sin \theta$.

Then, square both sides. On the left, you'll have $16 \cos^2 \theta$, which you can replace with $16(1 - \sin^2 \theta)$, and you can then reorganise everything into a quadratic equation in terms of $\sin \theta$.

Once you've solved that, though, you'll need to check the two answers you get, because one of them will not be a solution to the original equation (it gets added to the system when you square everything).

Comment: Did you check to see whether this idea was already presented one of the other times this question came up?

Comment: I did, and it helps that every one of the links you offered as a potential duplicate is asking a different question.

Comment: @ConMan:  with this method, I got only one answer (repeated root)

Comment: Asking a different question, maybe, but a question where the methods that arise are applicable to solving the current question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the equation as $\quad 4\cos\theta=5-3\sin \theta$.

Now $ \cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} $, so setting $\:s=\sin\theta$, we obtain the irrational equation
$$\pm4\sqrt{1-s^2}=5-3s \iff 16(1-s^2)=(5-3s)^2.$$
Of course, one possibly has to eliminate the solution(s) of this equation such that $\;|s|>1$.

Comment: I got only one (repeated) solution to $16(1-s^2)=(5-3s)^2$

Comment: You're right ($3/5$?). I had a sign error in my calculations, so I'll remove the last sentence, which is indeed useless. Thank's for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider a right triangle $ABC$, with right angle in $A$, and with $a=5, \; b=3, \; c=4$.

Then $\theta$ is the angle ...

Comment: Did you check to see whether this idea was already presented one of the other times this question came up?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I quickly checked the two posts you linked at the beginning, and I did not see an explicit mentioning of this approach. But if there is somewhere else, no problem to cancel this.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to solve the general problem of $$a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta = c$$

**Way 1**

A cool way to solve it is using the tan-half-angle substitution $t = \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)$ with 
$$ \begin{aligned} 
 \sin \theta & = \tfrac{2 t}{1+t^2} & \cos \theta & = \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
\end{aligned} $$

This turns the trig problem into a polynomial

$$ a \tfrac{2 t}{1+t^2} + b \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = c $$
$$ 2 t a + (1-t^2) b = (1+t^2) c $$
$$ t = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 +b^2-c^2}}{b+c} $$

and finally $$ \boxed{ \theta  = 2 \tan^{-1}(t) }$$

**Way 2**

Split the angle into two parts $\theta = x +y $ and expand the sine and cosine

$$ \sin \theta  = \cos x \sin y + \sin x \cos y $$
$$ \cos \theta  = \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y $$

Together you have

$$ a \left(\cos x \sin y + \sin x \cos y\right) + b \left(\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y\right) = c $$

which you re-arrange as

$$ \cos x  \underbrace{ \left( b \cos y + a \sin y \right)}_{\text{make zero} } + \sin x \left(a \cos y -b \sin y \right) = c $$

Solve as two equations with $$b \cos y + a \sin y  = 0 $$

$$ y = -\tan^{-1} \left(\tfrac{b}{a}\right) $$

and

$$ \sin x \left( a \cos y + b \sin y \right) = c $$

$$ \sin x \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = c $$

$$ x = \sin^{-1} \left( \tfrac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \right) $$

Or altogether

$$ \boxed{ \theta  = \sin^{-1} \left( \tfrac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \right) -\tan^{-1} \left(\tfrac{b}{a}\right) } $$

Comment: The problem is that both of these give you $\theta$, but the question asks for $\sin\theta$, so you'd still have to do something to convert the results back. They are useful tricks in general though.

Comment: Once you know $\theta$ you know $\sin \theta$, but if you are looking for a _direct_ way to solve for the sine, then use $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ like the other answers.